# Is it possible to automatically trigger a created action in a forked repo on upstream tag creation with Github Action workflow?

Tags: github, workflow, action

I created fork repository at github. Is that posable to trigger workflow based on tag creation in upstream repo?
Thanks

fork repo and created action under fork repo. I need to trigger this action if tag created in upstream repo

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.